# T4 Template debugger shows incorrect lines while multiple TT files included

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, t4

I am trying to debug the following T4 template file using VS2010 professional , windows 7.

But debugger doesn't highlight the Correct line in the File : "Texttemplate2.tt"

File 1: File1.tt

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>

<#@ include file="Texttemplate2.tt"  #>

<#

System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();


    int a= 10;

    Write("ASS");

    GetProperty("User","UserName");

#>
```

File : Texttemplate2.tt

```
<#@ template debug="true" hostspecific="true" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Xml" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.IO" #>
<#+

 public void Load()
    {
        string doc=null;
        if(doc == null)
        {
            string templateDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Host.TemplateFile);
            string absolutePath = Path.Combine(templateDirectory,"../../App_Data/EntityUI_MetaData_Appsettings.xml");
        }
    }
 public string GetProperty(string Entity, string prop)
    {
         Load();
         string node="none";

         if (node != "0" )
         {
            if (node == Entity )
              {
                return node;
              }
         }
        return null;
    }
 #>
```

Let me explain the question in detail.I have created the above two T4 template files. Now I want to debug my T4 template file "File1.tt" Code ( not the generated code). what I did I launched debugger with

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

and set breakpoints

```
int a= 10;
```

.pressing F5 now caused my breakpoint is to be hit.

```
int a= 10;
```

its now highlighted with YELLOW COLOR as BACKGOUND and YELLOW ARROW as in LEFT . press F11 thereafter until you reach

```
GetProperty
```

when this method is called into there you will notice that YELLOW ARROW , means current executing statement is not highlighted.

Meant, supppose Line:20 is the next executing statement , the debugger highlights line:10 in texttemplatefile2.tt

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. I haven't found a way to get the line to be correct. However, I have found that you can add

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

At the line you want to test, and then debug the T4 template. Your IDE will still be on the wrong line, but if you go to the place in your code that triggered the break - where the break *should* be - you can at least inspect the variables at that point.

**Warning:** If you try to save or run the template with the debugger line, it sometimes crashes Visual Studio. Comment it out immediately when you aren't using it.